# executorservice not killing thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

**Code:**

```
//List all threads:
Set<Thread> runningThreads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
System.out.println(runningThreads.toString());

//Thread creation:
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executorService.execute(this);

//Thread termination:
executorService.shutdownNow();

//List all threads:
Set<Thread> runningThreads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
System.out.println(runningThreads.toString());
```

I would expect the list that gets printed out to be exactly the same both times but what I'm getting is a print out of the thread that was created included in the results

How do I completely destroy a thread so that it's nowhere to be found?

Comment: You should wait for the completion of shut down process. The threads may not be terminated yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`shutdownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) attempts to stop the running thread, but as its API documentation says:

> This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. Use `awaitTermination` to do that.

So the thread may still be running when the code after the call to `shutdownNow()` returns. Note also that you need to make sure that the task running in the thread actually terminates; `shutdownNow()` is not going to kill the thread, it will just try to interrupt it.

As the documentation says, call [`executorService.awaitTermination(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) after calling `shutdownNow()` to wait until the thread has stopped.

Comment: What if it never terminates? It seems even if I put `awaitTermination` for days, it will just hang and never actually kill the thread

Comment: @Hooli: you never show the task that you're submitting to the executor. if it doesn't quit in response to interruption (eats the InterruptedException and keeps on looping, or blocked on I/O) then it won't terminate.

Comment: @NathanHughes: Would it be a good idea to change my thread from `while (true) {...}` to `while (!this.isInterrupted()) {...}`?

Comment: @Hooli: not `this.isInterrupted`, you want `!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. but you also have to make sure the interrupted flag is set at that point; throwing InterruptedException clears the interrupted flag. but if you think you can do `this.isInterrupted()` it sounds like you're passing a Thread into the executorService. which is bad, it should be a Runnable or Callable.

Comment: @NathanHughes: Any ideas on how to get around the `InterruptedException` when calling `executorService.awaitTermination` after interrupting a thread? (if `awaitTermination` is in a `try-catch`)

Comment: I got around this by using my own `Boolean` instead of `.interrupt()`

Comment: @Hooli you need a `volatile` Boolean, or an `AtomicBoolean`, not a plain `Boolean`, for visibility reasons.

Comment: @GPI: What do you mean? Do you have a link to explain in more detail?

Comment: All data that is shared between threads need to be memory-synchronized.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/106787/179850